# How does the login authentication work in Vaadin Bakery App

Tags: java, polymer, web-component, vaadin10

I am trying to learn vaadin JAVA framework. I am looking at the code of Bakery App. In `LoginView.java` there is call to `setAction('login')` that takes care of the successfull authentication. I want to know where in the code this is taking place. I just want to add a new username and password to the exisitng code. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bakery app uses Spring Security to handle login logic. Spring Security is configured in class `SecurityConfiguration`. The users are loaded/saved within `UserRepository` which extends `JpaRepository` which is part of the Spring Data JPA framework. This repository saves entities inside Bakery app in memory by default which is mentioned in the `README.md`:

> 3. Optionally you might want to avoid the data generator to be run on each single reload, therefore, make H2 database store entities in
>      file-system instead of in memory by adding the following lines to the
>      `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/bakery-test-data
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The place where those users are created and saved into memory is in `DataGenerator` Line 77  - 81:

```
    User baker = createBaker(userRepository, passwordEncoder);
    User barista = createBarista(userRepository, passwordEncoder);
    createAdmin(userRepository, passwordEncoder);
    // A set of products without constrains that can be deleted
    createDeletableUsers(userRepository, passwordEncoder);
```

This would be the place where you could add additional users.

Comment: thanks. I have looked in `SecurityConfiguration`. Suppose I am logged in successfully. How is it redirecting to `storefront`?

Comment: When logged in succesfully the redirection to StorefrontView ist realized inside the LoginView inside the method beforeEnter (LoginView is implementing BeforeEnterObserver):```@Override
 public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
  if (SecurityUtils.isUserLoggedIn()) {
   // Needed manually to change the URL because of https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4189
   UI.getCurrent().getPage().getHistory().replaceState(null, "");
   event.rerouteTo(StorefrontView.class);
  }
 }```

Comment: I have commented that line `event.rerouteTo(StorefrontView.class);`. But is is still redirecting.

Comment: Hmm.. good point! I'm pretty surprised by that myself. I think it's the combination of .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL) where LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login" (in `SecurityConfiguration`), the annotation attribute `startPath` = "login" in `MainView` and the `Route` annotation in `StoreFrontView` (`@Route(value = BakeryConst.PAGE_STOREFRONT, layout = MainView.class)`). But I don't know how the mechanism works exactly then.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I am trying this tutorial "https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login"

Comment: there is a call `successHandler(new savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())` in `SecurityConfiguration`. Is it doing anything?

Comment: It seems like it is part of the redirect magic. If you add a Breakpoint at `onAuthenticationSuccess` (in `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`) you will pass `this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);` where the target url is "/". The JavaDoc says: `Following a successful authentication, it decides on the redirect destination, based on the following scenarios` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194816/discussion-between-sudipta-roy-and-codinghaus).